How to fetch data from Fatek PLC through Profinet protocol using Python program
Currently I have a requirement to fetch data from Fatek PLC. Engineering team used Profinet protocol and they have given me the IP address of the PLC and the registers. I have done these type of tasks by a Python program but not to a Fatek PLC. So, I'm looking for an answer for this.
I searched on Google and read the PLC manual also, but no clue for Fatek with Profinet.
